# Does the monster's class/type matter?

Tags: diablo-iii

All monsters have a type or a class.  For example beast, undead or demon (as seen in the picture):

[image]

Do these types have any affect on the game play?  Are there any weapons or skills that are more effective against certain types of monster than others?  Are some types of monster more resistant, or even immune, to certain types of damage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are certainly some items that modify damage according to the monster type, for example [the legendary Monster Hunter sword](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/monster-hunter) has increased damage against beasts.

I *think* monsters of a similar type also tend to have similar resistances, but got no solid facts regarding that.

Comment: is this the only such piece of gear or are there other? And do different types of enemies have different resistance to damage types?

Comment: @IlyaMelamed there are others, for example [Genzaniku](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/item/genzaniku).

Answer (score 0):

The monsters type is important ^^
They can be resistant to a kind of weapon and weak against other types.

For example the undead is resistant to hack and slash weapons like swords and axes, but are very weak against blunt weapons like maces and scepters ^^ 
There are some hero ability more efficient against a type of monsters.

In this wikia you can read some Enemy Class information.
This is the [Undead page](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Undead)
And this is the [Beastiary page](http://diablo.wikia.com/wiki/Diablo_III_Bestiary)

Comment: Some of this information seems to derive from Diablo II. I think maybe you should find more reliable sources to back your answer.

Comment: The diablo series have a kind of "standard base" of gameplay and hero/monster interaction so i think this information is valid in diablo III too ^^

Comment: @Shyghar, do you have any sources confirming that this is true to D3 as well as D2?

Comment: I read this somewhere but i don't remember where.. 
In this article the author says that the hero/monsters interaction was like in the diablo II weackness and resistence included.

Comment: Considering how much has changed from D2; not sure how much assumptions we can make from older info